# Accord.Net binomial probability mass function result differs from Excel result

Tags: c#, .net, excel, accord.net

I'm trying to implement some functionality that was formerly provided via an Excel sheet into a C# application, but the [probability mass function of Accord.NET](http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Statistics_Distributions_Univariate_BinomialDistribution.htm) differs for some reason from the excel function.

In excel the probabilty mass function, is used [this way](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/binom-dist-function-HP010335671.aspx)

```
=BINOM.DIST(250; 3779; 0.0638; FALSE)

Result: 0.021944019794458
```

When I try it with Accord.NET

```
var binom = new BinomialDistribution(3779, 0.0638);
binom.ProbabilityMassFunction(250);

// Result: Infinity
```

But the cumulative distribution seems to work properly (except for the last few digits, but I assumed this is just some kind of precision error)

Excel:

```
=BINOM.DIST(250; 3779; 0.0638; TRUE)

Result: 0.736156366002849
```

Accord.NET:

```
var binom = new BinomialDistribution(3779, 0.0638);
binom.DistributionFunction(250);

// Result: 0.736156366002318
```

Why are the results so different? And is there a way to get the Excel result with Accord?

**EDIT:** [Extreme.Numerics](http://www.extremeoptimization.com/) calculates the same result as Excel, but I don't want to use this library, as the license system of this library always led to trouble in the past.

**EDIT 2:** Seems like some kind of overflow error.

When I use this I get the right result:

```
Math.Exp(binom.LogProbabilityMassFunction(250));
```

Any ideas why this could be happening?

Comment: The second parameter is a double for sure, and it would be implicitly converted to double if this would not be the case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Inspecting the source code of Accord.NET implementation it can be seen that `ProbabilityMassFunction` works like this:

```
//...
return Special.Binomial(numberOfTrials, k) * Math.Pow(probability, k)
            * Math.Pow(1 - probability, numberOfTrials - k);
```

In your case `numberOfTrials` is `3779` and `k` is `250`. Binomial function of `3779` over `250` is [more than 10<sup>398</sup>](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=binom%283779,%20250%29), which [seems too much for the `double` data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx) (approximate range is up to a bit more than 10<sup>308</sup>). So you get `Infinity` in the first multiplication term, which determines the final result here.

I'm not sure how `Extreme.Numerics` implements that, but your results suggest that they do it in a more clever way. Also, sadly it doesn't seem that Accord.NET provides `decimal` version of their interface.

---

This issue seems to have been fixed in the latest Accord.NET implementation. The implementation [looks now as follows](https://github.com/accord-net/framework/blob/1c7ee87628a26b485db8d1482ca49f2979184a47/Sources/Accord.Statistics/Distributions/Univariate/Discrete/BinomialDistribution.cs#L300):

```
double log = Special.LogBinomial(numberOfTrials, k) + k * Math.Log(probability)
    + (numberOfTrials - k) * Math.Log(1 - probability);

return Math.Exp(log);
```